# PowerBI: Create New Column for VLOOKUP-Like Operation Based on Unique Identifier in Related Tasks on the same table

Tags: powerbi

For simplification, I have a table as below which has the name of the task, its unique identifier, and the task that it is related to using the unique identifier. I want to create a new column in PowerBI where it looks for the unique identifier and brings the name of the task (instead of the identifier). A sort of a lookup.

I tried something like that (and many variations such as creating a copy of the table instead of using the same one):

= each if [OutwardRelates] = [Issue key] then [Summary] else null

Any ideas on how it can be achieved?
I created a table in Excel to show what I meant. Basically, it is the yellow column I want to create.

[image]